# On the definition of tensor product for modules of commutative and non-commutative rings.

Tags: category-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a ring and $M_A$ and  $_AN$ be two $A$-modules. The tensor product $T = M \otimes_A N \in \mathsf{Ab}$ for $A$ non necessarily commutative is an abelian group, where as the tensor product $T' = M \otimes_A N$ of $M$ and $N$ as $A$-modules over a commutative ring has the structure of an $A$-module.

When $A$ is commutative, can $T$ be given an $A$-module structure such that $T \simeq T'$ in $A-\mathsf{mod}$? Is this a 'canonical' construction? If so, I would highly appreciate a categorical reformulation of this statement.

Comment: Don't you answer your own question? As abelian groups, $T=T'$ by definition, so indeed when $A$ is commutative $T$ has a structure of $A$-module, which is what you call $T'$.

Comment: That's what I am missing, as far as I know $T$ is a quotient of a free abelian group whereas $T'$ is the quotient of a free $A$-module (hence canonically an $A$-module itself). Would you mind making this construction explicit?

Comment: @qualcuno If you go through the construction of the noncommutative tensor product, you'll find that you quotient out by middle-linearity. The obstruction to making $T$ into a module over $A$ is that it carries no natural left or right action; however, if $A$ is commutative or if the modules are actually bimodules, you can push the structure through to give left and right actions on $T$, as well as the desired isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to see this, but one is the following: in general, if $M$ is an $A$-$B$-bimodule and $N$ is a $B$-$C$-bimodule, then we can define $M\otimes_B N$, and it is an $A$-$C$-bimodule. We get the relations $mb\otimes n = m\otimes bn$, $a\cdot (m\otimes n)=(am)\otimes n$ and $(m\otimes n)\cdot c = m\otimes (nc)$.

Now a right $A$-module is the same thing as a $\mathbb{Z}$-$A$-bimodule, and a left $A$ module is the same thing as a $A$-$\mathbb{Z}$-bimodule, so in the setting of the question, we get $M\otimes_A N$, which is a $\mathbb{Z}$-$\mathbb{Z}$-bimodule, which is the same thing as an abelian group.

But when $A$ is commutative, $M$ and $N$ are both $A$-$A$-bimodules in a canonical way (the left and right actions of $A$ are the same, which makes sense because $A$ is commutative), so $M\otimes_A N$ is also an $A$-$A$-bimodule, and it is easy to check that the left and right action of $A$ coincide, so this is just an $A$-module. (Very quickly, $a(m\otimes n)=am\otimes n = m\otimes an = (m\otimes n)a$).